# Extract numbers just before the specific word/text

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have some strings such as

- 70cl duty free utscsx6
- 5cl csx192
- 1 ltr duty free uts csx12
- 5cl csx192

I would like to extract `70cl`,`5cl`,`1 ltr`,`5cl` in differnt rows.
Here each example represents individual observation.

Comment: Try this: `gsub("(?<=cl|ltr).*", "", df$row , perl = T)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the fragment you want to match is at the **start** of a source row.

Note also that it:

- starts with a non-empty sequence of digits,
- can be followed a space,
- then there is a unit of measure - a non-empty sequence of letters,
- and finally, **after** the text to match, there is a space.

So, translating it into regex terms, the regex can be:

```
^\d+ ?[a-z]+(?= )
```

with `g` and `m` options (global, and *^* matches start of each line).

For a working example see https://regex101.com/r/b4NdNb/1. Each match contains just what you want.